# How to get values and atributes of this XML in php?

Tags: php, xml

I have such php code:

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_file('2.xml', 'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA); 

print_r($xml);
```

How to get values of:
DialingNumber,StartTime,AnswerTime ?

```
foreach ($xml as $show)
  {
  echo (string)$show['DialedNumber'];
  echo (string)$show['AnswerNumber'];
  echo (string)$show['WaitDuration'];
  }
```

NOT WORKING ! How to get values of: DialingNumber,StartTime,AnswerTime ?

Comment: *NOT WORKING !* means what? Errors? Undesired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are problems with the the XML file itself, which can be 'corrected' with just replacing some of the entities with some dummy data.  The second part is to reference the correct path to the data you want to output.

```
$filename = '2.xml';
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
$data = str_replace(["&rs", "&rc"], "", $data);    // Remove entity references
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

foreach ($xml->Tablix1->DialedNumber_Collection->DialedNumber->Details_Collection->Details
        as $details)
{
    echo (string)$details['DialedNumbers'].PHP_EOL;
    echo (string)$details['AnswerNumber'].PHP_EOL;
    echo (string)$details['WaitDuration'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as below?

```
foreach ($xml as $show)
  {
  echo (string)$show[0]['DialedNumber'];
  echo (string)$show[0]['AnswerNumber'];
  echo (string)$show[0]['WaitDuration'];
  }
```

Comment: Eyup Toprak,
I tried your code it NOT show anything. Empty.